# Convert html to pdf automatically using ASPOSE in Java

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf  using aspose,also i have to use PageSize A1,A2,A3,A4 .this is worked perfectly..but i dont want set pagesize for pdf generation.So far i have tried below code

```
HtmlLoadOptions htmloptions = new HtmlLoadOptions(basePath);

htmloptions.getPageInfo().setWidth(PageSize.getA2().getWidth());
htmloptions.getPageInfo().setHeight(PageSize.getA2().getHeight());

// Load HTML file
Document doc = new Document(basePath + "400010_DOC002_L_10_2508016.html", htmloptions);
// Save HTML file

doc.save("D:/Web+URL_output.pdf");
```

Can anyone suggest with out set page size i have convert html to pdf conversion ? or else  please let me know what tools are available for this. Please let me know any other tools for this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

@Shankar, you may use the below code sample in order to convert an HTML file to a PDF file without setting page size. By default, the page size of the rendered PDF file will be as of the A4 page size.

Simply omit the code which is setting a page size, else remains the same.

```
        HtmlLoadOptions htmloptions = new HtmlLoadOptions(basePath);

        // Load HTML file
        Document doc = new Document(basePath + "400010_DOC002_L_10_2508016.html", htmloptions);

        // Save HTML file
        doc.save("D:/Web+URL_output.pdf");
```

Please let us know if you need any further assistance. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: I tried this code already. By default, the page size of the rendered PDF file will be as of the A4 page size. but my output pdf height and width not properly aligned. then i set A2 page size after that i can able to view entire data

Comment: i tried this code already.i know By default, the page size  is A4. but my pdf output not properly aligned height and width. when i used page size A2 output pdf properly aligned and able to view data in pdf. i dont want set pagesize. but i want automatically convert entire html to proper pdf output.

Comment: I humbly request you to share your source HTML file in Aspose.Pdf support forum for further investigation on our end. Aspose.Words and Aspose.Html can also convert an HTML file to a PDF file and we are hopeful that your HTML file will be converted to a PDF file as per your requirements.

Comment: how can i share my source html?

Comment: You may share the file by uploading it to a third party storage including Dropbox, Google Drive, One Drive etc. However, if you are concerned about data privacy and do not want to share it publicly, then you may share it with us by creating a post, with the file as an attachment, over Aspose.Pdf support forum so that we may proceed further to help you out.